# Filter on collection of NSManaged Obejct does not work

Tags: swift, collections, nsmanagedobject

I try to apply filter "by date" on my Comment's object collection, but the classic syntax that i use usually dosen't work! I get some error message!

Here you can find error message :
[image]
here an exemple of the syntaxe of my filter :

[image]

And here you find my Comment object :
[image]

Do you have any idea : how can I do that ?

Comment: Please post actual code instead of images (screenshot of error is fine, of course, but not screenshots of code).

Comment: The filter closure takes a *single* argument (`$0` in shorthand notation) which is the current array element to which the closure is applied. `$1` in the filter closure makes not sense. What are your trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to filter any element of my collection by our date properties.

Comment: So what should `$1.date` be in the closure?

Comment: Because by fisrt, i try to filter my collection by date, and for each filterd element of my collection i try to do something else.
The syntax of comments.filter({$0.date.timeIntervalSinceDate($1.date) < 0 }) is used to work : I already use it somewhere else in my code and it works fine.

Comment: That's wrong. Perhaps you mean `sort()` instead of `filter()` ?

Comment: I replace filter by sorted, and it works great. tnx